# Legacy GeoLite City provides incorrect country

Tags: geoip

(I'm using MaxMind's databases)

I'm using SourceMod which is a game server management addon for Source Engine, which provides plugin support.

Two months ago, I have added a plugin that does the following:

1. Check if the connecting user is from Israel. (Where I host the server, you're required to speak Hebrew in order to play)
2. If the user is not from Israel, check if his IP address is whitelisted. If it isn't, disallow the connection.

Now recently, one of the Israeli ISPs got new IP addresses (all starting with 77.138.*.*) which GeoLite shows as if they're French. So far I've got to whitelist 12 IP addresses because of this.

SourceMod has a third-party API that lets me use GeoLite2 City, GeoLite City (free ones) and GeoIPCity/GeoIPISP if I own them. For now I've tried using both of the free databases, sadly, no success.

I know MaxMind will update GeoLite again in 6 days. What I'm afraid of, is that I'm not going to achieve anything because MaxMind doesn't offer support for GeoLite, so I might be stuck with outdated databases that provide incorrect information.

What is a recently updated alternative that uses the same format as GeoLite (either legacy or new), or, is it 100% confirmed that those incorrect locations for IPs will be updated soon for GeoLite? I really don't feel like spending cash monthly just for GeoIP.

Comment: You could [submit a correction to MaxMind](https://support.maxmind.com/geoip-data-correction-request/). Corrections are rolled into GeoLite.

Comment: I thought they don't. Thanks!